# Can a java DataSource be converted to another DataSource type like a HikariDataSource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, mybatis

I have a situation where I am not in control of the type of DataSource I receive and cannot update the DataSource sent to me. I receive an Apache Commons BasicDataSource from version 1.4. Is there any way to convert this to either a newer version of BasicDataSource after receiving it, or even, convert it to a HikariDataSource?

For reference, here is a code scenario:

```java
@Bean("dataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
    try {
        return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource("jdbc/my_ds_name");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Could not lookup data source!");
    }
}
```

Also, I have tried casting to another DataSource type, but the username and password seem to get lost during the cast. I get whatever the JndiDataSourceLookup provides here. The reason this is an issue is due to the fact that the BasicDataSource (v1.4) is not compatible with the latest versions of MyBatis (3.5.x >=). I get the following error right now:

```java
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method org/apache/commons/dbcp/DelegatingResultSet.getObject(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; is abstract
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getObject(DelegatingResultSet.java) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.LocalDateTypeHandler.getNullableResult(LocalDateTypeHandler.java:38) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.LocalDateTypeHandler.getNullableResult(LocalDateTypeHandler.java:28) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.getResult(BaseTypeHandler.java:85) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createRowKeyForMappedProperties(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:1057) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createRowKey(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:1019) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.applyNestedResultMappings(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:946) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getRowValue(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:434) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValuesForNestedResultMap(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:909) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:326) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:301) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:194) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:65) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:79) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:325) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:89) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:147) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:427) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.selectList(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:224) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:147) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:80) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:152) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:85) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
```

Comment: If you have access to the connection properties you can just create a HikariDataSource bean.

Comment: You are doing a lookup frmo JNDI. So no you cannot. Unless the type registered in JNDI is changed you cannot **or** you stop using JNDI and configure the datasource yourself. Also the error is about mybatis using a newer JDBC version then the current datasource implementation you are using is calling a non-implementted method. Either downgrade mybatis or define the datasource yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can convert one DS to Another DS. Below is the solution for Jndi convert to HikariDatasource

```
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
             DataSource jndiDataSource = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:jboss/datasources/JndiName");
        HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
             ds.setDataSource(jndiDataSource);
```